# linux + print the root file system size

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, perl

lvs is good command to show us the file system size as

```
lvs
  LV      VG   Attr       LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  lv_root vgW -wi-ao---- 100.00g
  lv_swap vgW -wi-ao----   7.72g
  lv_var  vgW -wi-ao---- 100.87g
```

I am trying to capture the root file system size

and until now I create the following syntax

```
lvs | awk  '$1 ~ /root/' | awk '{print $NF}' | sed s'/\./ /g' | awk '{print $1}'
```

and its print  ( expected output is 100 )

```
100
```

but I want to improve my syntax to be better

any suggestions ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`lvs` shows information about LVM volumes. It can give you the size of the block device that contains the root filesystem (not the size of that filesystem) if that filesystem happens to be on a LVM volume and if you know which one (and no, the name of the logical volume does not *have* to have "root" in it).

```bsh
size=$(
  lvs --unit b --nosuffix --no-headings --config 'log{prefix=""}' -o size vgW/lv_root
)
```

To find out the size of the block device that contains the root filesystem, whether it's a LVM volume or disk partition or NBD/loop/md... device (but note that the root file system doesn't have to backed by  a block device like for network filesystems, zfs, btrfs...), on Linux, I'd use `lsblk` instead:

```bsh
size=$(
  lsblk -Jbo size,mountpoint | jq '.blockdevices[]|select(.mountpoint=="/").size'
)
```

To find the size of the `/` filesystem, you could use `df` (assuming GNU `df`) or `findmnt`:

```bsh
size=$(findmnt -bno size /)
```

```bsh
size=$(df -B1 --output=size / | awk 'NR==2{print $1}')
```

Those give you the size in bytes, that is, with the most precision. If you want the size rounded down to an integer number of gigabytes, just divide by 1000000000:

```bsh
gigabytes=$((size / 1000000000))
```

Or to get it in gibibytes (note that `lvs` uses 1024 based suffixes, where `g` means gibibyte, not gigabyte), use:

```bsh
gibibytes=$((size / 1024 / 1024 / 1024))
```

Though all commands above also allow specifying a different unit (but beware of  gigabyte vs gigibyte and that most will give you floating point numbers and may do the rounding differently and use different characters for the decimal radix depending on the locale).

Answer (score 3):

You could easily integrate all that in one `awk` call:

```
lvs | awk '$1=="lv_root" {split($4,a,"."); print a[1]}'
```

This will inspect the first field end process only the line where this is equal to `lv_root`. It will then split the 4th field at the `.` into the array `a` and print the first entry, corresponding to the part before the `.`.

The same can be achieved by printing the size as integer using `printf`, which also truncates floating-point numbers to the nearest *smaller* integer (and interestingly disregards the "text parts" behind the numerical part, in this case the `g`):

```
lvs | awk '$1=="lv_root" {printf "%d\n",$4}'
```

**Note** that this is not equal to rounding the size to the nearest integer. If you want to accomplish that, you can use

```
lvs | awk '$1=="lv_root" {printf "%.0f\n",$4}'
```

Comment: `awk '$1~/root/{print $NF+0}'` is also good I reckon.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '$1 ~/root$/{gsub(/\..*/,"",$NF);print $NF}' filename
```

output

```
praveen:/tmp$ awk '$1 ~/root$/{gsub(/\..*/,"",$NF);print $NF}' filename
100
praveen@praveen:/tmp$
```